# Does HATEOAS contemplate hypermedia in the Error Response?

Tags: error-handling, hateoas

In a Hypermedia-Driven RESTful solution, should I include relevant HATEOAS links in Error responses?

For instance, let's imagine we have a Microservices architecture.

We have FooSvc and BarSvc, where Bar resources are associated in a 1:1 relation with Foo resources, but managed independently (e.g. we have Projects that we can create just to present them, and then we can decide to Manage a project in our platform).

So, we can try to fetch the Bar resource associated with Foo with id 1 using GET `/foo/1/bar` (not caring how the request is routed downstream to the BarSvc).

Since there is no such Bar instance created yet, the service will retrieve a 404 response. Should that response include hypermedia links to point out how this can be created (e.g. a HAL `_links` field with a link to POST `/foo/1/bar`)?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, in fact, [RFC7807 - 'Problem Details for HTTP APIs'](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) can help with this, and the most popular frameworks should provide support for it (as for example the Spring HATEOAS library [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#mediatypes.http-problem))

Also, there is a proposed [`vnd.error` mime type](https://github.com/blongden/vnd.error) for this (further explained in [this post](https://nocarrier.co.uk/the-error-hypermedia-type/)), but it seems it has been superseded by RFC7807 mentioned above, at least Spring deprecated this in favor of the Problem Details approach ([here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/2.0.0/api/org/springframework/hateoas/mediatype/vnderrors/package-summary.html))